# Reducing the number of ticks in the colorbar using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I reduce the number of ticks on the colorbar and ensure that the values are equi-spaced? Basically, the 8 color bands have to be equally spaced between `Amin=257` and `Amax=454` i.e. the length of each colorband =`(Amax-Amin)/8`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm
import math
from  numpy import nan

fig,aPe = plt.subplots(1)
n=3

N=2*n*(n-1)

J = np.array([[]])
Pe=np.array([[394.20560747663563, 408.7929050665396 , 419.132709901089  ,
        398.95097406721044, 403.81198021076113, 430.00914784982064,
        424.50127213826016, 453.54817733128607, 441.4651085668709 ,
        447.42507960635163, 413.8982415602072 , 390.3025816600353 ],
            
[394.20560747663563, 408.7929050665396 , 419.132709901089  ,
         398.95097406721044, 403.81198021076113, 430.00914784982064,
         424.50127213826016, 453.5481773312857 , 347.7309476270773 ,
         257.42585381716805, 413.8982415602072 , 390.3025816600353 ]])         
             
C1 = nan
for i in J[0]:
    Pe = np.insert(Pe, i, [C1], axis=1)
print("Pe =", [Pe])

for i in range(0,len(Pe)):
    Max=max(max(Pe[i]), max(Pe[i]))
    Min=min(min(Pe[i]), min(Pe[i]))
a=Min
b=Max
Amax= math.ceil(Max)
Amin= math.floor(Min)
print(Amax, Amin)

color = cm.get_cmap('Dark2')
norm = Normalize(vmin=Amin, vmax=Amax)
color_list = []
for i in range(len(Pe[0])):   
    color_list.append(color(((Pe[0,i])-Amin)/(Amax-Amin)))
    
id = 0
for j in range(0, n):
    for k in range(n-1):
        aPe.hlines(200+200*(n-j-1)+5*n, 200*(k+1)+5*n, 200*(k+2)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
        id += 1

    for i in range(0, n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i, 200+200*j), 10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        aPe.add_patch(rect)
        if j < n-1:
            aPe.vlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200*(n-1-j)+5*n, 200*(n-j)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
            id += 1

cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm), ticks=np.arange(Amin, Amax+len(color.colors), len(color.colors)))
cb.set_label("Entry pressure (N/m$^{2}$)")
aPe.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
aPe.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created the colorbar, add this line to set the ticks to the way shown in your pic.

```
cb.set_ticks(np.arange(Amin, Amax+1, (Amax-Amin)/8).astype(np.int64))
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't give me what I am looking for. For instance, ```366``` is at the center of the green band, ```344``` is at the center of the pink band. I want the values to be at the ends of the colorbands.

Comment: My bad.... was to be divided by 8, not 9. Check now